# Visual Basic, MySql generate id number when idnumber exist

Tags: mysql, vb.net-2010

I am trying to make a auto generated idnumber(PK) it will perform when i press autogenerate number but it still displaying the number that i just added heres my code pls help.

```
Dim reader as MySqlDataReader
Dim rdm As New Random

Idnumber.text = (rdm.next(0,5))

Dim comp As String
comp = "select from information where idnumber'" & idnumber.text &"'"
cmd = cmd.executereader()

if sqlds.tables(0).rows.count > 0 then
  'This will perform button perform click
End if
```

Comment: Sorry for the improper text im using chrome on android phone

Comment: I'm confused about what's going on here. What is `hridnumber.text`, it is not declared anywhere? And your sql command is invalid as there is no `=`. Please explain what exactly you are trying to achieve as it is not particularly clear

Comment: Well i want is before i add a record in mysql database it will check the id number if exist in the database if the number exist it will pick number between 1-5 then add it on the database

Comment: @user8077340 Why do you want to generate the idnumber by yourself for the primary key instead of using the AUTO INCREMENT feature in MySQL?

Comment: Well it is for id number i want is unique and not a counting numbers. Sorry for the wrong grammer hehe

Answer (score 0):

```
DIm rdm as new random

Idnumber.text = (rdm.next(0,5))

Dim comp As String
comp = "select from information where idnumber'" & idnumber.text &"'"
Dim reader as MySqlDataReader = cmd.executereader()

if reader.hasrows then
    Idnumber.text = (rdm.next(1,5))
end if
```

this method can have a duplication on your idnumber thats why  rdm.next(1,5)
 ill give you a tip search for guid!